# Replace entire DIV with a custom DIV using JQuery in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension in Chrome for an internal tool we use. We have had this tool for a few years and the navigation menu has never worked in Chrome. The developers refuse to fix it. So part of what I am attempting to do with my extension is to replace the menu with a functioning menu.

Currently the menu is wrapped in a DIV. I want to replace that entire DIV with a new DIV with a working menu. At first I thought it would easy enough to use JQuery's replaceWith() function but replaceWith() only seems to work on single pieces of code. I was able to easily replace the entire Menu with a single element. Then I came across .load() but I was not able to successfully get the .html file in the extension folder to actually load.

I shortened this menu but it is an example of the current DIV:

```
<div id="ctl00_MasterMenu" class="MenuStyle ctl00_MasterMenu_5" style="height:20px;">
<span class="MenuItemStyle ctl00_MasterMenu_4">
<a class="ctl00_MasterMenu_1 MenuItemStyle ctl00_MasterMenu_3" href="default.aspx" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Home</a>
</span> 
<span class="MenuItemStyle ctl00_MasterMenu_4">
<a class="ctl00_MasterMenu_1 MenuItemStyle ctl00_MasterMenu_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterMenu','o6')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">New Ticket Expand New Ticket</a>
</span> 
</div>
```

And I basically want to replace it with something like:

```
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>New Item</li>
<li>New Item2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But the items in your example do not match the items in your desired outcome. Where is "New Item" and "New Item2"?

Comment: Terry - The <UL> stuff is going to replace everything in the <DIV> so really the DIV stays but everything between <div></div> gets replaced with the <ul></ul> stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the children in the `<div>` and replace them with `<li>`, and then finally replace the parent element with `<ul>`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $menu = $("#ctl00_MasterMenu");

    $menu.children("span").each(function(index) {
        $(this).replaceWith("<li>"+$(this).html()+"</li>");
    });

    $menu.replaceWith("<ul>"+$menu.html()+"</ul>");
});
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/fuE37/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
// store the parent div's info
var $parent = $('#ctl00_MasterMenu');
var parentID = $('#ctl00_MasterMenu').attr('id');
var parentClass = $('#ctl00_MasterMenu').attr('class');
var parentStyle = $('#ctl00_MasterMenu').attr('style');

// create li elements for each of the spans
$parent.children().each(function(index, child){
    $(child).replaceWith('<li class="'+$(child).attr('class')+'">'+$(child).html()+'</li>');
});

// create the ul element and copy the attributes
$parent.children().wrapAll('<ul id="'+parentID+'" class="'+parentClass+'" style="'+parentStyle+'"/>');

// remove the old div
$parent.replaceWith($parent.html());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/aMm5t/1/